# Can you link two entity framework models?

Tags: entity-framework

First, this is the 3.5 version of EF, not the new 4 version.

Here's a simple made up example of what I'm after.

Imagine in the first EDMX we have objects for employee and department.
Imagine in the second EDMX we have objects for orders.

Both EDMX models point to the same database.

1. Is it possible to have the EDMX use employee from the first model on the order of the second model?
2. Can you change the namespace of different objects in the same EDMX?
3. For bonus points, and more out of curiosity, if order were in a separate database, could I have orders use a foreign key from employee's primary key?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx) but working with such connected models is quite hard (advanced) because you will lose designer support and you will have to maintain models as XML files. Also it is supported only in CSDL layer of EDMX file so MSL and SSDL must be shared. The reference between CSDLs can be only one way so `Order` will be able to use `Employee` and `Department` but `Department` and `Employee` will have no knowledge about `Order` (or reverse behavior if you make reference in opposite direction).

It would be much easier to merge those two EDMXs into single one.

Answer (score 1):

A post from 2008 by the Lead EF developer discusses 2 solutions to this:

- a.  Multiple CSDL files(Models) while sharing MSL and SSDL.
- b.  Divide application schemas into different sets of CSDL, MSL and
  SSDL files.

Looks like solution (a) is what Ladislav Mrnka was speaking of.

Post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx